# Pasar un valor de columns de datatable por url

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

```
columns: [
    {"data": "id_periodo"},
    {"data": "periodos"},
    {"data": "estado"},
    {"defaultContent": "<button  type='button' class='btn btn-success btn-sm editar_periodo' > 
    <i class='fas fa-edit'></i></button>"+'&nbsp;&nbsp'+
    "<button type='button' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm eliminar_periodo'><i class='fas fa- 
    trash'></i> </button>"},
    {"defaultContent": "<a href='cursos.php?id'>Crear Cursos</a>"}
```

Necesito pasar el {"data":"id_periodo"} por url a traves de una etiqueta <a href'curso.php?id'>
Espero me puedan ayudar o recomendar algo, muchas gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido, primero, date una vuelta por el [Tour de StackOverflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) así aprendes el uso de las etiquetas, y debo informarte de que tu aplicación es vulnerable a ataques [XSS (cross-site scripting)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) , no es recomendable que utilices el JSON para pasar código HTML, lo debes utilizar para pasar datos, no estructuras.

Comment: Muchas gracias, la verdad no tengo mucho conocimientos, soy nuevo en esto. Tomare en cuenta tu comentario y estudiare sobre eso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo le crearía una clase ".crear" a la etiqueta "a", y al atributo href le quito la el direccionamiento a cursos.php, para luego con jquery recoger con el evento clic los valores de esa fila y enviar el id_periodo mediante el método post.

```
columns: [
    {"data": "id_periodo"},
    {"data": "periodos"},
    {"data": "estado"},
    {"defaultContent": "<button  type='button' class='btn btn-success btn-sm editar_periodo' > 
    <i class='fas fa-edit'></i></button>"+'&nbsp;&nbsp'+
    "<button type='button' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm eliminar_periodo'><i class='fas fa- 
    trash'></i> </button>"},
    {"defaultContent": "<a class="crear" href='#'>Crear Cursos</a>"}
    ]
```

Jquery

```
// ------------------ CREAR --------------------------
$("#miTabla tbody").on("click",".crear", function(){
    // recogemos los datos de la fila y los asignamos a la variable data
    let data = datatable.row($(this).parents()).data();
    // asignamos a la variable id_periodo el valor que está en data
    let id_periodo = data.id_periodo
    
    $_post("cursos.php",id_periodo,(response) => {
        // aquí se procesa lo devuelto por el archivo cursos.php
    });
    
});
```

Puedes ver un ejemplo de un crud con datatables en:
https://github.com/luispiedrahitanet/datatables_crud

✔